# Moving a partial playlist to another playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Do not want to move the whole playlist. I do know how to move videos from one playlist to another by 1 at a time. I do not want to move the whole playlist only a fraction of the total. 250 videos are currently in it I would like to move15-18% ~.  I am stunned how limiting the options are for something this little. Pretty minimalistic UI. Any help would be wonderful. Again not trying to move the whole list to combine with another. I hve that covered.